# How to pass and read multiple params in URL - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

There are 2 views with respective controllers.
The links are in View1.Clicking on this link should load View2 and also read the parameters.
This is what I have tried but the alert says - undefined.
View2 can load with/without params - each case having a different workflow.

**View1.html:**

```
<div ng-controller="view1ctrl">
<a href="#/view2/pqid/775/cid/4" >Link1</a>
</div>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'App/views/view1.html',
        controller: 'view1ctrl'
        })
        .when('/view2', {
            templateUrl: 'App/views/view2.html',
            controller: 'view2ctrl'
        })
        .when('/view2/:pqid/:cid', {
            templateUrl: 'App/views/view2.html',
            controller: 'view2ctrl'
        })            
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/view1'
        });
}]);
```

**view2ctrl.js:**

```
app.controller("view2ctrl", ['$scope','$routeParams',function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    var init = function () {
        alert($routeParams.pqid);
}
init();
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there:

```
.when('/view2/:pqid/:cid'
```

maps to a URL in this format :

```
view2/1234/4567
```

1234 being the pqid and 4567 the cid.

So your routing, I think is working, just change the link to #/view2/775/4.

Or if you want to keep the same link change your routing to:

```
#/view2/pqid/:pqid/cid/:cid
```